# Kotlin Pair being used but method expects android.util.Pair

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a PreferencesManager written in Java with the following method:

```
 public void insert(Pair<String, Object> keyValue, boolean async) {
```

And from kotlin I'm trying to insert a new Pair into the PreferencesManager like so:

```
 val  p = Pair(SharedPreferencesManager.STATIC_KEY, value)
            preferencesManager!!.insert(p, false)
```

However i'm getting an error saying:

> "Required android.util.Pair, found kotlin.Pair"...

Is there a way I can convert from one to the other?

Comment: Kotlin's Pair class doesn't reflect anything in Java, because Java has no Pair class. `android.util.Pair` is separate from Java.

Comment: I see, and is there a way i can utilise the android Pair inside kotlin such that the method accepts the parameter?

Comment: Androd's Pair takes the same arguments in the constructor. Just change your import.

Comment: I have "import android.util.Pair" in my imports where im trying to insert, but it doesn't seem to make a difference

Comment: Don't use a Pair then. It's really not meant to be used for interop, but rather as a temporary holder when constructing Maps.

Comment: My entire java implementation uses a Pair to pass through a key, value object to a preferences manager, can't really change that at the moment sadly. Would having a different method signature with some sort of Tuple work instead?

Comment: Why not make another method that takes two arguments instead of a Pair and then construct a Pair with those to pass to your current method?

Comment: I believe wanderer is telling you *remove* "import android .util.Pair, and *replace it* with the kotlin Pair... Your comment to his comment seems like you read his comment backwards...

Comment: @TobyEggitt i tried that too and it didnt work.

Comment: @TheWanderer a destructured method did the trick, thanks! if you want to give it a formal answer i'll mark it as correct :)

Comment: I would suggest using the fully qualified name of android.util.Pair instead of importing it, or importing andoid.util.Pair using the `as` keyword.  The `kotlin` package is always imported, and I believe since Pair is already defined there, any other Pair class that is imported is going to be shadowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kotlin has its own Pair, which isn't an extension or proxy for `android.util.Pair`. Try using a helper method instead:

```
public void insert(String key Object value, boolean async) {
    Pair<String, Object> pair = new Pair<>(key, value);
    insert(pair, async);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

As an alternative to the [answer @TheWanderer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52592825/kotlin-pair-being-used-but-method-expects-android-util-pair#comment92120678_52592825) gave in the comments of the question.  I would suggest importing android.util.Pair using the `as` keyword as follows:

```
import android.util.Pair as APair
//....
val  p = APair(SharedPreferencesManager.STATIC_KEY, value)
preferencesManager!!.insert(p, false)
```

See the [kotlin docs on importing for more](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/packages.html#imports).  The kotlin package is always going to imported, and apparently will take precedence over classes from other packages unless you rename them or fully qualify them.

Comment: Clever way of getting around a Type issue.  Effectively a type alias like I use in Swift on a regular basis.  Thanks for showing this.